# minify php -- disable rewriting of css uri's is not working

Tags: php, minify

According to docs at http://code.google.com/p/minify/wiki/UriRewriting

```
$min_serveOptions['rewriteCssUris'] = false;
```

I should be able to add the above to my configuration file and it will disable uri rewriting. The reason I want to disable it, is because I don't need it. All my css/js files are in one folder and not nested at all. It is rewriting the urls. For example

Example:

```
min_extras/cli/minify.php -o ../../css/all.css ../../css/phppos.css ../../css/menubar.css ../../css/general.css ../../css/popupbox.css ../../css/register.css ../../css/receipt.css ../../css/reports.css ../../css/tables.css ../../css/thickbox.css ../../css/datepicker.css ../../css/editsale.css ../../css/footer.css ../../css/css3.css ../../css/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.css ../../css/jquery.loadmask.css ../../css/jquery.ui.all.css ../../css/paginate.css
```

Before:

```
background-image: url("../images/header/header_empty.png");
```

After:

```
background-image:url("s/header/header_empty.png");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your "$min_serveOptions['rewriteCssUris'] = false;" is put in a wrong place.

in file minify.php (version 2.1.5) at line 84 change:

```
$combined = Minify::combine($sources) . "\n";
```

to:

```
$min_serveOptions = array('rewriteCssUris'=>false);
$combined = Minify::combine($sources,$min_serveOptions) . "\n";
```

then everything works as you expexted